# Fixed Menu bar not working on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

Hi I have coded a menu bar that appears after 850px it works fine on Safari but on Chrome and Firefox it isn't working. here is the code:

```js
     (function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
  $('#bar').fadeIn(500);
 } else {
  $('#bar').fadeOut(500);
    }

     });
     });
     })(jQuery);
```

```css
#bar { 
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
     color:#FFF;
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-weight:100;
       font-size: 28px;
    line-height:75px;
       height: 75px;
       background: #000000;
       color: #fff;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">Test</div>
```

Can any one help?

Comment: This is not working :/ It shows up on chrome and firefox but doesn't stick to the top of the browser like it does on safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `body{margin:0;}` to your css.

Chrome has a default of 8px margin to the top. That is why it doesn't fix all the way to the top but 8px below.

```js
     (function($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
  $('#bar').fadeIn(500);
 } else {
  $('#bar').fadeOut(500);
    }

     });
     });
     })(jQuery);
```

```css
#bar { 
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
     color:#FFF;
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-weight:100;
       font-size: 28px;
    line-height:75px;
       height: 75px;
       background: #000000;
       color: #fff;
    padding-top:10px;
}

body{margin:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">Test</div>    

A vitae scelerisque maecenas vestibulum est nec vel facilisi condimentum ac consectetur maecenas donec vulputate dapibus a nascetur vehicula. Sit dignissim arcu curabitur varius mus aptent suspendisse commodo a imperdiet a parturient a feugiat habitant at suspendisse. Hac aliquet diam in libero eros etiam nascetur porttitor rhoncus fusce tincidunt adipiscing in potenti facilisis in. Turpis a eu tincidunt adipiscing nam himenaeos diam condimentum vestibulum parturient porta risus senectus sit posuere mus sapien a. Natoque etiam felis sodales cras pretium sit dignissim convallis nunc a luctus montes senectus dictum. Vel scelerisque ac ipsum adipiscing dolor mollis natoque placerat quam aenean phasellus vestibulum id parturient nulla cubilia adipiscing ut potenti vestibulum eros dis ullamcorper eu. 

Senectus parturient ipsum adipiscing felis metus consequat erat elit arcu sed a diam id euismod leo lacus fusce id eget condimentum amet condimentum montes lacinia praesent cum cum. Bibendum a metus himenaeos a ante adipiscing eu parturient tincidunt a adipiscing scelerisque etiam a scelerisque malesuada proin. Ad a scelerisque scelerisque urna iaculis adipiscing ultricies a adipiscing in metus gravida dictumst ut quam egestas sapien auctor tortor parturient eu semper. 

Scelerisque tortor curabitur eget blandit nullam at lorem vestibulum tincidunt scelerisque curae sociis volutpat consequat eros suspendisse a vulputate. Et class phasellus risus parturient massa donec venenatis vitae adipiscing vel convallis torquent felis lectus adipiscing fames vestibulum parturient aptent diam vitae non vulputate quisque mi dapibus id nec. Vestibulum nunc suscipit condimentum enim habitasse commodo curae adipiscing penatibus leo sem a vestibulum semper consectetur adipiscing curae inceptos non cursus lorem scelerisque quisque mi vestibulum eros vitae. Morbi fusce ullamcorper magna mi phasellus eleifend curae a facilisi parturient orci nulla himenaeos tempor maecenas. A phasellus sodales eleifend nulla tempor natoque condimentum vestibulum parturient tristique dignissim elit nibh hac placerat suspendisse diam a a magnis scelerisque lacinia. Magnis libero leo placerat in metus senectus malesuada elementum per faucibus consectetur orci a imperdiet eget non enim condimentum luctus a suspendisse natoque suspendisse litora ullamcorper. 

Eu montes justo nec luctus mi vehicula praesent dolor congue nisi fames quisque diam elementum ad ac inceptos. Elit a malesuada morbi consectetur curae parturient magna ad suspendisse a ultricies faucibus ullamcorper scelerisque curabitur sociis. Scelerisque vulputate himenaeos imperdiet erat nec a vestibulum a parturient tincidunt pretium consectetur scelerisque scelerisque sociosqu vestibulum parturient est. A a a parturient ad bibendum ut leo a at habitasse torquent adipiscing et elementum nisi a vestibulum egestas condimentum cursus ultrices feugiat vestibulum parturient auctor a. Nisl id a elementum porttitor eu nascetur eros praesent ullamcorper in eu cum habitasse parturient integer eleifend purus. Porta habitant magna at praesent sed parturient condimentum urna interdum pulvinar justo parturient luctus purus. 

Consequat nibh a pretium lectus lacinia magnis rhoncus suspendisse in risus facilisi molestie malesuada mi sodales in est iaculis amet class vel porta. Ridiculus lacinia per ullamcorper porta condimentum sem ut vitae sit phasellus iaculis auctor proin posuere conubia non consectetur a ultricies mus ac adipiscing ultricies auctor volutpat parturient. In habitasse mollis consectetur ac senectus mattis quam tempor facilisis penatibus vestibulum suspendisse nunc tristique pharetra sit imperdiet.

A vitae scelerisque maecenas vestibulum est nec vel facilisi condimentum ac consectetur maecenas donec vulputate dapibus a nascetur vehicula. Sit dignissim arcu curabitur varius mus aptent suspendisse commodo a imperdiet a parturient a feugiat habitant at suspendisse. Hac aliquet diam in libero eros etiam nascetur porttitor rhoncus fusce tincidunt adipiscing in potenti facilisis in. Turpis a eu tincidunt adipiscing nam himenaeos diam condimentum vestibulum parturient porta risus senectus sit posuere mus sapien a. Natoque etiam felis sodales cras pretium sit dignissim convallis nunc a luctus montes senectus dictum. Vel scelerisque ac ipsum adipiscing dolor mollis natoque placerat quam aenean phasellus vestibulum id parturient nulla cubilia adipiscing ut potenti vestibulum eros dis ullamcorper eu. 

Senectus parturient ipsum adipiscing felis metus consequat erat elit arcu sed a diam id euismod leo lacus fusce id eget condimentum amet condimentum montes lacinia praesent cum cum. Bibendum a metus himenaeos a ante adipiscing eu parturient tincidunt a adipiscing scelerisque etiam a scelerisque malesuada proin. Ad a scelerisque scelerisque urna iaculis adipiscing ultricies a adipiscing in metus gravida dictumst ut quam egestas sapien auctor tortor parturient eu semper. 

Scelerisque tortor curabitur eget blandit nullam at lorem vestibulum tincidunt scelerisque curae sociis volutpat consequat eros suspendisse a vulputate. Et class phasellus risus parturient massa donec venenatis vitae adipiscing vel convallis torquent felis lectus adipiscing fames vestibulum parturient aptent diam vitae non vulputate quisque mi dapibus id nec. Vestibulum nunc suscipit condimentum enim habitasse commodo curae adipiscing penatibus leo sem a vestibulum semper consectetur adipiscing curae inceptos non cursus lorem scelerisque quisque mi vestibulum eros vitae. Morbi fusce ullamcorper magna mi phasellus eleifend curae a facilisi parturient orci nulla himenaeos tempor maecenas. A phasellus sodales eleifend nulla tempor natoque condimentum vestibulum parturient tristique dignissim elit nibh hac placerat suspendisse diam a a magnis scelerisque lacinia. Magnis libero leo placerat in metus senectus malesuada elementum per faucibus consectetur orci a imperdiet eget non enim condimentum luctus a suspendisse natoque suspendisse litora ullamcorper. 

Eu montes justo nec luctus mi vehicula praesent dolor congue nisi fames quisque diam elementum ad ac inceptos. Elit a malesuada morbi consectetur curae parturient magna ad suspendisse a ultricies faucibus ullamcorper scelerisque curabitur sociis. Scelerisque vulputate himenaeos imperdiet erat nec a vestibulum a parturient tincidunt pretium consectetur scelerisque scelerisque sociosqu vestibulum parturient est. A a a parturient ad bibendum ut leo a at habitasse torquent adipiscing et elementum nisi a vestibulum egestas condimentum cursus ultrices feugiat vestibulum parturient auctor a. Nisl id a elementum porttitor eu nascetur eros praesent ullamcorper in eu cum habitasse parturient integer eleifend purus. Porta habitant magna at praesent sed parturient condimentum urna interdum pulvinar justo parturient luctus purus. 

Consequat nibh a pretium lectus lacinia magnis rhoncus suspendisse in risus facilisi molestie malesuada mi sodales in est iaculis amet class vel porta. Ridiculus lacinia per ullamcorper porta condimentum sem ut vitae sit phasellus iaculis auctor proin posuere conubia non consectetur a ultricies mus ac adipiscing ultricies auctor volutpat parturient. In habitasse mollis consectetur ac senectus mattis quam tempor facilisis penatibus vestibulum suspendisse nunc tristique pharetra sit imperdiet.

A vitae scelerisque maecenas vestibulum est nec vel facilisi condimentum ac consectetur maecenas donec vulputate dapibus a nascetur vehicula. Sit dignissim arcu curabitur varius mus aptent suspendisse commodo a imperdiet a parturient a feugiat habitant at suspendisse. Hac aliquet diam in libero eros etiam nascetur porttitor rhoncus fusce tincidunt adipiscing in potenti facilisis in. Turpis a eu tincidunt adipiscing nam himenaeos diam condimentum vestibulum parturient porta risus senectus sit posuere mus sapien a. Natoque etiam felis sodales cras pretium sit dignissim convallis nunc a luctus montes senectus dictum. Vel scelerisque ac ipsum adipiscing dolor mollis natoque placerat quam aenean phasellus vestibulum id parturient nulla cubilia adipiscing ut potenti vestibulum eros dis ullamcorper eu. 

Senectus parturient ipsum adipiscing felis metus consequat erat elit arcu sed a diam id euismod leo lacus fusce id eget condimentum amet condimentum montes lacinia praesent cum cum. Bibendum a metus himenaeos a ante adipiscing eu parturient tincidunt a adipiscing scelerisque etiam a scelerisque malesuada proin. Ad a scelerisque scelerisque urna iaculis adipiscing ultricies a adipiscing in metus gravida dictumst ut quam egestas sapien auctor tortor parturient eu semper. 

Scelerisque tortor curabitur eget blandit nullam at lorem vestibulum tincidunt scelerisque curae sociis volutpat consequat eros suspendisse a vulputate. Et class phasellus risus parturient massa donec venenatis vitae adipiscing vel convallis torquent felis lectus adipiscing fames vestibulum parturient aptent diam vitae non vulputate quisque mi dapibus id nec. Vestibulum nunc suscipit condimentum enim habitasse commodo curae adipiscing penatibus leo sem a vestibulum semper consectetur adipiscing curae inceptos non cursus lorem scelerisque quisque mi vestibulum eros vitae. Morbi fusce ullamcorper magna mi phasellus eleifend curae a facilisi parturient orci nulla himenaeos tempor maecenas. A phasellus sodales eleifend nulla tempor natoque condimentum vestibulum parturient tristique dignissim elit nibh hac placerat suspendisse diam a a magnis scelerisque lacinia. Magnis libero leo placerat in metus senectus malesuada elementum per faucibus consectetur orci a imperdiet eget non enim condimentum luctus a suspendisse natoque suspendisse litora ullamcorper. 

Eu montes justo nec luctus mi vehicula praesent dolor congue nisi fames quisque diam elementum ad ac inceptos. Elit a malesuada morbi consectetur curae parturient magna ad suspendisse a ultricies faucibus ullamcorper scelerisque curabitur sociis. Scelerisque vulputate himenaeos imperdiet erat nec a vestibulum a parturient tincidunt pretium consectetur scelerisque scelerisque sociosqu vestibulum parturient est. A a a parturient ad bibendum ut leo a at habitasse torquent adipiscing et elementum nisi a vestibulum egestas condimentum cursus ultrices feugiat vestibulum parturient auctor a. Nisl id a elementum porttitor eu nascetur eros praesent ullamcorper in eu cum habitasse parturient integer eleifend purus. Porta habitant magna at praesent sed parturient condimentum urna interdum pulvinar justo parturient luctus purus. 

Consequat nibh a pretium lectus lacinia magnis rhoncus suspendisse in risus facilisi molestie malesuada mi sodales in est iaculis amet class vel porta. Ridiculus lacinia per ullamcorper porta condimentum sem ut vitae sit phasellus iaculis auctor proin posuere conubia non consectetur a ultricies mus ac adipiscing ultricies auctor volutpat parturient. In habitasse mollis consectetur ac senectus mattis quam tempor facilisis penatibus vestibulum suspendisse nunc tristique pharetra sit imperdiet.

A vitae scelerisque maecenas vestibulum est nec vel facilisi condimentum ac consectetur maecenas donec vulputate dapibus a nascetur vehicula. Sit dignissim arcu curabitur varius mus aptent suspendisse commodo a imperdiet a parturient a feugiat habitant at suspendisse. Hac aliquet diam in libero eros etiam nascetur porttitor rhoncus fusce tincidunt adipiscing in potenti facilisis in. Turpis a eu tincidunt adipiscing nam himenaeos diam condimentum vestibulum parturient porta risus senectus sit posuere mus sapien a. Natoque etiam felis sodales cras pretium sit dignissim convallis nunc a luctus montes senectus dictum. Vel scelerisque ac ipsum adipiscing dolor mollis natoque placerat quam aenean phasellus vestibulum id parturient nulla cubilia adipiscing ut potenti vestibulum eros dis ullamcorper eu. 

Senectus parturient ipsum adipiscing felis metus consequat erat elit arcu sed a diam id euismod leo lacus fusce id eget condimentum amet condimentum montes lacinia praesent cum cum. Bibendum a metus himenaeos a ante adipiscing eu parturient tincidunt a adipiscing scelerisque etiam a scelerisque malesuada proin. Ad a scelerisque scelerisque urna iaculis adipiscing ultricies a adipiscing in metus gravida dictumst ut quam egestas sapien auctor tortor parturient eu semper. 

Scelerisque tortor curabitur eget blandit nullam at lorem vestibulum tincidunt scelerisque curae sociis volutpat consequat eros suspendisse a vulputate. Et class phasellus risus parturient massa donec venenatis vitae adipiscing vel convallis torquent felis lectus adipiscing fames vestibulum parturient aptent diam vitae non vulputate quisque mi dapibus id nec. Vestibulum nunc suscipit condimentum enim habitasse commodo curae adipiscing penatibus leo sem a vestibulum semper consectetur adipiscing curae inceptos non cursus lorem scelerisque quisque mi vestibulum eros vitae. Morbi fusce ullamcorper magna mi phasellus eleifend curae a facilisi parturient orci nulla himenaeos tempor maecenas. A phasellus sodales eleifend nulla tempor natoque condimentum vestibulum parturient tristique dignissim elit nibh hac placerat suspendisse diam a a magnis scelerisque lacinia. Magnis libero leo placerat in metus senectus malesuada elementum per faucibus consectetur orci a imperdiet eget non enim condimentum luctus a suspendisse natoque suspendisse litora ullamcorper. 

Eu montes justo nec luctus mi vehicula praesent dolor congue nisi fames quisque diam elementum ad ac inceptos. Elit a malesuada morbi consectetur curae parturient magna ad suspendisse a ultricies faucibus ullamcorper scelerisque curabitur sociis. Scelerisque vulputate himenaeos imperdiet erat nec a vestibulum a parturient tincidunt pretium consectetur scelerisque scelerisque sociosqu vestibulum parturient est. A a a parturient ad bibendum ut leo a at habitasse torquent adipiscing et elementum nisi a vestibulum egestas condimentum cursus ultrices feugiat vestibulum parturient auctor a. Nisl id a elementum porttitor eu nascetur eros praesent ullamcorper in eu cum habitasse parturient integer eleifend purus. Porta habitant magna at praesent sed parturient condimentum urna interdum pulvinar justo parturient luctus purus. 

Consequat nibh a pretium lectus lacinia magnis rhoncus suspendisse in risus facilisi molestie malesuada mi sodales in est iaculis amet class vel porta. Ridiculus lacinia per ullamcorper porta condimentum sem ut vitae sit phasellus iaculis auctor proin posuere conubia non consectetur a ultricies mus ac adipiscing ultricies auctor volutpat parturient. In habitasse mollis consectetur ac senectus mattis quam tempor facilisis penatibus vestibulum suspendisse nunc tristique pharetra sit imperdiet.

A vitae scelerisque maecenas vestibulum est nec vel facilisi condimentum ac consectetur maecenas donec vulputate dapibus a nascetur vehicula. Sit dignissim arcu curabitur varius mus aptent suspendisse commodo a imperdiet a parturient a feugiat habitant at suspendisse. Hac aliquet diam in libero eros etiam nascetur porttitor rhoncus fusce tincidunt adipiscing in potenti facilisis in. Turpis a eu tincidunt adipiscing nam himenaeos diam condimentum vestibulum parturient porta risus senectus sit posuere mus sapien a. Natoque etiam felis sodales cras pretium sit dignissim convallis nunc a luctus montes senectus dictum. Vel scelerisque ac ipsum adipiscing dolor mollis natoque placerat quam aenean phasellus vestibulum id parturient nulla cubilia adipiscing ut potenti vestibulum eros dis ullamcorper eu. 

Senectus parturient ipsum adipiscing felis metus consequat erat elit arcu sed a diam id euismod leo lacus fusce id eget condimentum amet condimentum montes lacinia praesent cum cum. Bibendum a metus himenaeos a ante adipiscing eu parturient tincidunt a adipiscing scelerisque etiam a scelerisque malesuada proin. Ad a scelerisque scelerisque urna iaculis adipiscing ultricies a adipiscing in metus gravida dictumst ut quam egestas sapien auctor tortor parturient eu semper. 

Scelerisque tortor curabitur eget blandit nullam at lorem vestibulum tincidunt scelerisque curae sociis volutpat consequat eros suspendisse a vulputate. Et class phasellus risus parturient massa donec venenatis vitae adipiscing vel convallis torquent felis lectus adipiscing fames vestibulum parturient aptent diam vitae non vulputate quisque mi dapibus id nec. Vestibulum nunc suscipit condimentum enim habitasse commodo curae adipiscing penatibus leo sem a vestibulum semper consectetur adipiscing curae inceptos non cursus lorem scelerisque quisque mi vestibulum eros vitae. Morbi fusce ullamcorper magna mi phasellus eleifend curae a facilisi parturient orci nulla himenaeos tempor maecenas. A phasellus sodales eleifend nulla tempor natoque condimentum vestibulum parturient tristique dignissim elit nibh hac placerat suspendisse diam a a magnis scelerisque lacinia. Magnis libero leo placerat in metus senectus malesuada elementum per faucibus consectetur orci a imperdiet eget non enim condimentum luctus a suspendisse natoque suspendisse litora ullamcorper. 

Eu montes justo nec luctus mi vehicula praesent dolor congue nisi fames quisque diam elementum ad ac inceptos. Elit a malesuada morbi consectetur curae parturient magna ad suspendisse a ultricies faucibus ullamcorper scelerisque curabitur sociis. Scelerisque vulputate himenaeos imperdiet erat nec a vestibulum a parturient tincidunt pretium consectetur scelerisque scelerisque sociosqu vestibulum parturient est. A a a parturient ad bibendum ut leo a at habitasse torquent adipiscing et elementum nisi a vestibulum egestas condimentum cursus ultrices feugiat vestibulum parturient auctor a. Nisl id a elementum porttitor eu nascetur eros praesent ullamcorper in eu cum habitasse parturient integer eleifend purus. Porta habitant magna at praesent sed parturient condimentum urna interdum pulvinar justo parturient luctus purus. 

Consequat nibh a pretium lectus lacinia magnis rhoncus suspendisse in risus facilisi molestie malesuada mi sodales in est iaculis amet class vel porta. Ridiculus lacinia per ullamcorper porta condimentum sem ut vitae sit phasellus iaculis auctor proin posuere conubia non consectetur a ultricies mus ac adipiscing ultricies auctor volutpat parturient. In habitasse mollis consectetur ac senectus mattis quam tempor facilisis penatibus vestibulum suspendisse nunc tristique pharetra sit imperdiet.

A vitae scelerisque maecenas vestibulum est nec vel facilisi condimentum ac consectetur maecenas donec vulputate dapibus a nascetur vehicula. Sit dignissim arcu curabitur varius mus aptent suspendisse commodo a imperdiet a parturient a feugiat habitant at suspendisse. Hac aliquet diam in libero eros etiam nascetur porttitor rhoncus fusce tincidunt adipiscing in potenti facilisis in. Turpis a eu tincidunt adipiscing nam himenaeos diam condimentum vestibulum parturient porta risus senectus sit posuere mus sapien a. Natoque etiam felis sodales cras pretium sit dignissim convallis nunc a luctus montes senectus dictum. Vel scelerisque ac ipsum adipiscing dolor mollis natoque placerat quam aenean phasellus vestibulum id parturient nulla cubilia adipiscing ut potenti vestibulum eros dis ullamcorper eu. 

Senectus parturient ipsum adipiscing felis metus consequat erat elit arcu sed a diam id euismod leo lacus fusce id eget condimentum amet condimentum montes lacinia praesent cum cum. Bibendum a metus himenaeos a ante adipiscing eu parturient tincidunt a adipiscing scelerisque etiam a scelerisque malesuada proin. Ad a scelerisque scelerisque urna iaculis adipiscing ultricies a adipiscing in metus gravida dictumst ut quam egestas sapien auctor tortor parturient eu semper. 

Scelerisque tortor curabitur eget blandit nullam at lorem vestibulum tincidunt scelerisque curae sociis volutpat consequat eros suspendisse a vulputate. Et class phasellus risus parturient massa donec venenatis vitae adipiscing vel convallis torquent felis lectus adipiscing fames vestibulum parturient aptent diam vitae non vulputate quisque mi dapibus id nec. Vestibulum nunc suscipit condimentum enim habitasse commodo curae adipiscing penatibus leo sem a vestibulum semper consectetur adipiscing curae inceptos non cursus lorem scelerisque quisque mi vestibulum eros vitae. Morbi fusce ullamcorper magna mi phasellus eleifend curae a facilisi parturient orci nulla himenaeos tempor maecenas. A phasellus sodales eleifend nulla tempor natoque condimentum vestibulum parturient tristique dignissim elit nibh hac placerat suspendisse diam a a magnis scelerisque lacinia. Magnis libero leo placerat in metus senectus malesuada elementum per faucibus consectetur orci a imperdiet eget non enim condimentum luctus a suspendisse natoque suspendisse litora ullamcorper. 

Eu montes justo nec luctus mi vehicula praesent dolor congue nisi fames quisque diam elementum ad ac inceptos. Elit a malesuada morbi consectetur curae parturient magna ad suspendisse a ultricies faucibus ullamcorper scelerisque curabitur sociis. Scelerisque vulputate himenaeos imperdiet erat nec a vestibulum a parturient tincidunt pretium consectetur scelerisque scelerisque sociosqu vestibulum parturient est. A a a parturient ad bibendum ut leo a at habitasse torquent adipiscing et elementum nisi a vestibulum egestas condimentum cursus ultrices feugiat vestibulum parturient auctor a. Nisl id a elementum porttitor eu nascetur eros praesent ullamcorper in eu cum habitasse parturient integer eleifend purus. Porta habitant magna at praesent sed parturient condimentum urna interdum pulvinar justo parturient luctus purus. 

Consequat nibh a pretium lectus lacinia magnis rhoncus suspendisse in risus facilisi molestie malesuada mi sodales in est iaculis amet class vel porta. Ridiculus lacinia per ullamcorper porta condimentum sem ut vitae sit phasellus iaculis auctor proin posuere conubia non consectetur a ultricies mus ac adipiscing ultricies auctor volutpat parturient. In habitasse mollis consectetur ac senectus mattis quam tempor facilisis penatibus vestibulum suspendisse nunc tristique pharetra sit imperdiet.
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it doesn't seem to work, In my CSS I have already set that Body margin 0,

If i scroll down and up really fast its at the top and then it fades out,

I want it to fade in like it does on safiri

Comment: @ThomasLarge So if you use the code snippet I provided and scroll down, you don't see it fading in ? Or what is the problem? Because I don't see a difference between safari and chrome atm.

Comment: @TeeDeeJee Yes I have used the Code that you have provided, but I have not change is there anyway that the CSS I have somewhere else could be affecting it?

Comment: @ThomasLarge Can you maybe provide a link then to the full site with the problem?

Comment: @TeeDeeJee I cant do that at the moment as the site is in development and I cant show the content of the site, Its all password protected